# What's the translation of “upcoding" in French?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, terminologie, santé-et-médecine

Upcoding [is](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/upcoding) the:

> practice in which provider services are billed for higher CPT procedure codes than were actually performed, resulting in a higher payment by Medicare or 3rd-party payor.

What's the translation of “upcoding" in French?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at a dictionnary?

Comment: @Toto yes, no success so far

Comment: What about [surfacturation](https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator#fr/en/surfacturation) -> "overbilling"?

Comment: @Toto that's a superset of upcoding

Comment: This seems to be very specific. I would guess each administration has its own word to name such a fraud (cause as I understand it, it is a fraud so that the provider gets more money with the end-user not actually paying more, but "medicare" well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le terme *surfacturation* proposé par [@Toto](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44428/whats-the-translation-of-upcoding-in-french#comment90439_44428) me parait assez précis.

Vous avez indiqué dans un commentaire que vous trouvez ce terme trop général.

Sur le site du Conseil national de l'Ordre des médecins, j'ai trouvé, à propos de l'article 29: [lien](https://www.conseil-national.medecin.fr/code-deontologie/devoirs-generaux-medecins-art-2-31/article-29-fraude-abus-cotations)

> Toute fraude, abus de cotation, indication inexacte des honoraires perçus et des actes effectués sont interdits.

Les terme *abus de cotation*, et sans doute *surcotation*, me semblent donc bien adaptés dans ce contexte médical.

Comment: _Abus de cotation_, vraiment excellent ! Il y a l'idée de faute et l'idée de gonflement lorsque appliqué à cotation, _surcotation_  ou _surclassement_ n'ayant pas directement cette idée-là. En plus la source est normative ; bonne recherche.

Comment: Très bonne réponse, c'est exactement à cela que je pensais en matière de mot spécifique.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't found a match for *upcoding* per se but that's certainly at least generally [*surfacturation*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/surfacturation/75700) ("Facturation d'un bien ou d'un service plus élevée que son coût réel, généralement effectuée dans une intention frauduleuse", Larousse online) as someone [commented](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44428/whats-the-translation-of-upcoding-in-french#comment90439_44428). In an entry for [overpricing](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=SURFACTURATION&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs), I found terminology which might be useful to at least explain what this is in French, including *surcotation, surtarification* and *majoration, gonflement*, relating to prices (*gonflement, majoration du/des prix*). I'm also thinking about [*surclassement*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/surclassement). The reason for these is trying to phrase and flesh something out such as *surfacturation par surclassement des actes médicaux* i.e. the means of overpricing/billing/invoicing is by (*par*) upgrading the class (*surclassement*) of the procedures...